# Building Spark with provided Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark

I've been trying to build a custom Spark build with a custom built Hadoop (I need to apply a patch to Hadoop 2.9.1 that allows me to use S3Guard on paths that start with `s3://`).

Here is how I build spark, after cloning it and being on Spark 2.3.1 on my `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG HADOOP_VER=2.9.1
RUN bash -c \
    "MAVEN_OPTS='-Xmx2g -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m' \
    ./dev/make-distribution.sh \
    --name hadoop${HADOOP_VER} \
    --tgz \
    -Phadoop-provided \
   -Dhadoop.version=${HADOOP_VER} \
   -Phive \
   -Phive-thriftserver \
   -Pkubernetes"
```

This compiles successfully, but when I try to use Spark with `s3://` paths I still an error on the Hadoop code that I'm sure I removed through my patch when compiling it. So that Spark build is not using my Hadoop provided JARs as far as I can tell.

What is the right way to compile Spark so that it does not includes the Hadoop JARs and uses the one I provide.

**Note**: I run on standalone mode and I set `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)` so that it points to my Hadoop classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom hadoop versions, you need to get your own artifacts onto the local machines, and into the spark tar file which is distributed round the cluster (usually in HDFS), and downloaded when the workers are deployed (in YARN; no idea about k8s)

The best way to do this reliably is to locally build a hadoop release with a new version number, and build spark against that.

```
dev/make-distribution.sh -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Pyarn -Pkubernetes -Phadoop-3.1 -Phadoop-cloud -Dhadoop.version=2.9.3-SNAPSHOT
```

That will create a spark distro with the hadoop-aws and matching SDK which you have built up.

It's pretty slow: run nailgun/zinc if you can for some speedup. If you refer to a version which is also in the public repos, there's a high chance whatever cached copies in your maven repo ~/.m2/repository has crept in.

Then: bring up spark shell and test from there, before trying any more complex setups.

Finally, there is some open JIRA for s3guard to not worry about s3 vs s3a in URLs. Is that your patch? If not, does it work? we could probably get it in to future hadoop releases if people who need it are happy

Comment: Indeed that is my path. We set the `s3://` handler to always be handled by `s3a` and wanted to keep using `s3://` but with s3guard support.

Comment: OK/. There's been some discourse a while back about not having the full s3a:// URL in the dynamodb table. It's not needed, after all. The specific FS instance would have the homework of adding its prefix. Nothing written yet though

Comment: What is the difference between `-Phadoop` and `-Dhadoop.version`? I thought only the latter was needed...